# FileNotFoundException while using ShaderbyteCode.CompilefromFile method

Tags: c#, slimdx

I'm currently learning SlimDX, I want to load a Shader from tutorial which is named "triangle.fx" and it is in a folder called "FX",everything is in my solution.
When I'm typing this line of code:

```
 using (var bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(@"FX/triangle.fx", "PShader", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None))
```

I'm getting FileNotFoundException, and I don't know why because everything exists in my solution.

Comment: I'm learning from tutorials from the homepage of Slimdx.
Even when I'm downloading the sample solution from the website, I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: Are your files being copied to the build target?

Comment: @RobStone, well I've just added a folder called "FX", then I have created a file called triangle.txt (because VS doesnt have any function for creating them), and I have changed it's extension to *.fx

Comment: The FX folder is in the same directory as the built .exe?

Comment: @RobStone
The .exe file is in bin/Debug/
And the FX folder is in the MySlimDXProject3 folder,same as bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the FX folder is a subdirectory of the folder containing the .exe. In this case /bin/debug/FX

Comment: But in the sample from slimdx.org it isn't.
This sounds silly.

Comment: That project is likely set to copy the folder when it builds

Comment: Wow,It worked, thank you kindly :).
By the way, you said that the project from slimdx.org is "set to copy the folder when it builds", how can I do the same with mine ?

Comment: You should be able to right click the folder in the solution explorer to change build actions.  The option you want might be content, though I can't recall it from my mobile.